# pig IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_CHARARRAY error

Tags: apache-pig

My table consists of 253 columns so loaded data to pig bag without schema method, when I apply filter condition to any data getting this error how to avoid it? Any jars needs to be added ?

> Error: IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_CHARARRAY

Answer (score 1):

Since schema is not defined in the load statement, so default data type for all the fields are `bytearray`.

Pig tries to implicitly cast from one type to another while using in the script.
All castings are not possible, so in that case, warnings are thrown.

You can refer the [Pig Cast operators](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#cast) for details

Answer (score 0):

When the schema is not specified the fields are loaded as `bytearray`.When you apply filter you will have to cast the field you are using for the filter.If you are filtering using a string use `(chararray)` in front of the field.

Comment: can u please send some sample query

Comment: Post your script and show where the error is coming from,I'll try to correct it. A = FOREACH B GENERATE  (chararray)COUNT(A) AS total; The datatype of total is casted from int to chararray